# How to use ocaml-top

Tags: macos, ocaml, typerex

I got a OCaml project for school and downloaded the template project they provide. Theres a file I need to edit called puzzle.ml. How do I use ocaml-top to edit/open the puzzle.ml file. I've been trying to troubleshoot this for hours and still no luck. Any tips or suggestions are appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Using Mavericks

Comment: At which part are you stuck? _(What are the steps you have tried so far?)_

Comment: i just dont know how to open the file using ocaml-top. I already navigated terminal into the project directory. I tried ocaml-top puzzle.ml. I dont know what command I should be using to use ocaml-top thats all.

Comment: Are you following these install steps _(on the ["Installation" section of this page](http://www.typerex.org/ocaml-top.html))_?

Comment: i already installed ocaml-top. I want to get into the editor and I do not know how

Comment: What happens if you type `ocaml-top` in terminal (on the command line)?

Comment: says command not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If simply running `ocaml-top` gives you an error that the command cannot be found, OPAM might not have set your `PATH` variable correctly, this can be fixed by adding the following to your shell config file:

```
export PATH=/Users/$USER/.opam/system/bin:$PATH #for bash
set PATH /Users/$USER/.opam/system/bin $PATH    #for fish
```

Comment: This. Fixed it for me, not sure why the path got messed up but ocaml-top command is now working. Thank you!

Comment: @CoderNinja, it seems that the OPAM initialization doesn't properly set the path if you modify it yourself. I also ran into this issue as seen in my comments below, but apparently this answer was too big of an edit so I just posted it myself. Glad it helped!

Comment: Is there a permanent fix for this? It seems that i have to do this everytime I reopen terminal

Comment: Like I said in my answer, add the appropriate line to your shell config file. ie. the `.bashrc` or equivalent for your shell.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, free book https://realworldocaml.org/ is your friend.

Second, ocamltop is not an editor, it is a running environment. You can use `#use "yourfile.ml"` to run your ocaml `ml` file.

Third, You can use whatever text editor to edit your source file.

Comment: well the ocaml top ppl show a nice looking editor on their website ad thats the thing you get with the windows installation. i was just wondering how to get that

Comment: The OP is referring to OCamlPro's ocaml-top interactive editor, not the built-in OCaml top-level.

Answer (score 1):

Everybody else thinks you mean the standard OCaml top-level. However, ocaml-top is a gtk-based editor for editing and evaluating OCaml code: http://www.typerex.org/ocaml-top.html

I just installed it on my OS X Maverics system, which was really quite difficult. You say you have it installed already. If so, that's impressive as I really found it difficult :-)

Now that I have it installed, I can run it by saying:

```
$ ocaml-top
```

In the Terminal (the command line). It looks pretty good, and it does let me edit and execute OCaml code. I've only tried a few simple things.

However, ocaml-top uses X11 to display its windows. So, you also need to have X11 installed on your OS X system.

Comment: I've installed ocaml-top, opam install ocaml-top tells me I have at least. But I can't find where the binary is located... Just using `ocaml-top` in the terminal tells me there is an invalid command.

Comment: So, it doesn't appear to be linked in the path.... and when I try running it from `/Users/$USER/.opam/sys/bin/`, it tells me that it failed to find logos in the a `data` directory that should be in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

One way to work is to have an editor window next to the ocaml toplevel and just cut'n paste the lines you want to test.

Do you have the ocaml documentation? If not get it. In the chapter about the toplevel you will find the way to read in a file.